# ng-repeat's element not updated on array modification when in a partial

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a similar issue to what is stated in the 2 posts below - I have 3 ng repeats in a partial, when I update the source arrays the changes are not reflected in the view.

[ng-repeat's element not updated on array modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797345/ng-repeats-element-not-updated-on-array-modification)

[AngularJS not refreshing ngRepeat when updating array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570570/angularjs-not-refreshing-ngrepeat-when-updating-array)

The ng repeats are within 3 ul's with each listing out input checkboxes with ng click on each, if I check an input from the the first list then my js code runs through the other 2 arrays, finds matching inputs and sets a property called IsSelected to true which is bound to ng checked of each input. e.g regions in the first list - if I check europe, then it checks all the European countries in the second list, and all the related cities in the 3rd list when I click on an apply button. $scope.$apply() after the js code for setting IsSelected doesnt work, but if I set the arrays to null then the view appears empty for that particular list. I then tried to use track with a property that constantly changes when I update the array elements like a guid but that  also doesnt work. If it was a scope issue then why would setting the array to null then update the view as suspected?

Comment: please enclose some code to illustrate that, and/or a live demo reproducing the issue.

Comment: btw, try to to set the flag properties for the checkboxes in a higher, common scope, e.g. `$rootScope`. save them to a property as an uneven matrix so their state won't get reset each time the ng-repeat scopes are binded.