# View is not updating in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app, i am calculating total bill and displaying on my view. First time its work fine. But when I increment the `$scope.bill_total` it is not updating the view. But in console it is changing. I have tried `$scope.$apply().` But it is throwing error.what are the reasons of view not get updating in general case Can anyone explain it?

HTML

```
 <div id="total" class="col col-30 cart-item text-right text-black">
            Bill Total<br/> ${{ bill_total }}
        </div>
<button class="button button-small button-light"  ng-click="increment()"> +</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.calculate = function () {
    $scope.bill_total = parseFloat($scope.gross_bill) + parseFloat($scope.taxes) + parseFloat($scope.tips);
}

$scope.calculate();

$scope.increment = function () {
    $scope.gross_bill++;
    $scope.calculate();
    console.log($scope.bill_total )
}
```

Comment: did u missed the semicolon in line `$scope.gross_bill++;`

Comment: Share a plunker with the relevant HTML and JS code..

Comment: can you post the error thrown ?

Comment: is it the fact you are missing a semicolon as Kalhano mentioned?

Comment: how do you call `$scope.increment`? by DOM event or `ng-click` or programmatically

Comment: I have updated $scope.gross_bill++; but still not working.

Comment: Yes, I am calling $scope.increment on ng-click event.

Comment: How do you use `ng-click`?

Comment: I have updated the qus. You can see It.

Comment: @Kalhano Toress Pamuditha what are the reasons of view not get updating in general case.

Comment: @ng_developer, view not get updating is usually due to binding change out of angular watch cycle, but that's seems not the case here. it's better to create a fiddle or plnkr to show your case.

Comment: It's working in my plunkr where I just copied your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/5u7fcBPxVU0HRhhodh04?p=preview. Can you please check what's the difference in your code?

Comment: Actually my code is too big and some of the value I ma getting from other controllers. So it is difficult to build plunker

Comment: @Wayne Ellery . your plunker is working. But why I ma facing problem It is crazy..

Comment: Make sure the button is within the same controller where you define `increment`.

Comment: Ya. It is in same controller.

Comment: i know this might not be an answer, but to test the scope thing, could you pls put your increment logic in a `setTimout` and do `$scope.$apply()` manually to see if the view changes?

Comment: sure.. I will try this too..

Answer (score 1):

Need to see more of your code, but why are you updating gross_bill when you are expecting bill_total to change?

If you aren't using gross_bill in your template, it won't be watched and hence changing it's value won't redraw the view.

So, modify things that are bound in your template. If there's some reason I'm wrong and you need to do scope.apply, and maybe that's the case, try wrapping your code in a $timeout which will trigger a digest, is the 'recommended' solution preferred to calling apply directly.

[notes on apply vs timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070822/angular-scope-apply-vs-timeout-as-a-safe-apply)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I must follow it.

Answer (score 1):

as we can only see part of your source code, it looks all good.
to test if everyting is in the same digest scope, you can manually do an async apply:

```
$scope.increment = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.gross_bill++;
        $scope.calculate();
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log($scope.bill_total );
    });
}
```

and pls also double check below points:

- if `bill_total` is one-time binding {{ ::bill_total }}
- if the directive scope is isolated with one-way binding `bill_total`

Comment: @ng_developer, is this part of code in a directive?

Comment: N0.. all code are in same controller. And I ma getting the update value in console when i increment the value.

Comment: weird, really cannot tell more base on the snippet, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is probably that `$scope.bill_total` is not an object and therefore cannot be watched. You need to change it to something like `$scope.bill_total = {value: 3}`.  Then when you update the value it should be updated correctly in your view. There should be no reason to call `$scope.apply` since you are within a digest cycle already.

Make sure to change your html to :

```
<div id="total" class="col col-30 cart-item text-right text-black">
  Bill Total<br/> ${{ bill_total.value }}
</div>
```

Comment: i don's see this is the root cause, angular can watch on primitive type