# Markers not appearing in leaflet

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, markers, angular-leaflet-directive

I am trying to load the position form the database and assign it to marker(lat, lng). But when I push the new marker to my markers array, the markers are not appearing on the leaflet map.

I am creating the marker like this.

```
$scope.markers = new Array();

$scope.alerts = Alert.query(function (){
        $scope.markers.push({
            lat: $scope.alerts[0].g_pos.coordinates[0],
            lng: $scope.alerts[0].g_pos.coordinates[1],
            message: "Added marker from query"
        });
        console.log($scope.markers[0].lat);
        console.log($scope.markers[0].lng);
    });
```

I am able to see the marker.lat and marker.lng with correct values in the console. Its just not appearing in the leaflet map.

I also tried using a watchCollection() but no luck.

```
$scope.$watch('markers', function(newMarkers, oldMarkers) {
        if (newMarkers.length > 0) {
            console.log(newMarkers[0].lat);
            console.log(newMarkers[0].lng);
        }           
    }, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your code with `$timeout`. In this way, AngularJS will know about your changes.

```
$scope.markers = new Array();

$scope.alerts = Alert.query(function (){
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.markers.push({
            lat: $scope.alerts[0].g_pos.coordinates[0],
            lng: $scope.alerts[0].g_pos.coordinates[1],
            message: "Added marker from query"
        });
        console.log($scope.markers[0].lat);
        console.log($scope.markers[0].lng);
    });
});
```

**Note:** You should `inject` the `$timeout` service into your controller.

Here is a [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070822/angular-scope-apply-vs-timeout-as-a-safe-apply) regarding this *issue*.

Also here is [an article](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html), where the author talks about the `$apply()` method, which is another solution for this.