# Angular: multiple Directives talk together. $apply/$emit/$broadcast confusion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

So I have two directives (Timeline and Displayer) instanciated in a controller.

When a click happens on Timeline, it `$emit`s a `TimelineClicked` event to the controller .

The controller `$on('TimelineClicked', cb)`, `$broadcast`s an `UpdateDisplay` event to Displayer .

I have two situations here :

1. `onUpdateDisplay` can be called during a `$digest` cycle, for example, on load, which updates UI
2. but when it comes from `TimelineClicked` *apparently* it is not `$digest`ed.

Hence wrapping the method with `$apply` like so:

```
$scope.onUpdateDisplay = function($event, activeObjects) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        //$scope values modification
    });
};
```

Will trigger an `$apply already in progress error` when in situation 1 and not it 2 .

I don't consider doing something like `if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest')` which is way too dirty IMHO.

- How should two directives talk together and make sure their scope is always up-to-date?
- Does the $apply cycle waits for events callbacks to finish?
- Should I wrap the `apply` somewhere else (around the `$on('TimelineClicked', cb)`)?

I have tried several configuration without success...

Comment: One option is, instead of calling `$scope.$apply` directly, you can use `$timeout(function(){ /* do something */ })` to ensure that it's safe.

Comment: It also sounds very hacky to me. But I tried ... without success.

Comment: Please show us some relevant code. Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/uLbv5n4k/

Comment: Been trying to reproduce in a Fiddle. Here's mine: http://jsfiddle.net/206e2cmh/1/ But it also works in the fiddle. Plus in between it got fixed on my code, I hardly know what changes I made for that. Sorry, all of this is not very helpful...

Comment: True, but unfortunately sometimes it's unavoidable, as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070822/angular-scope-apply-vs-timeout-as-a-safe-apply
You should aso take a look at this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply%28%29