# Update textbox value $on event

Tags: angularjs

I have the following eventhandler:

```
$scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, data) {

        switch (data.model) {
            case "ImageFile":
                self.item.ImageFile = data.file;
                self.item.ImageFileName = data.file.name;
                break;
           default:
                self.item.IconFile = data.file;
                self.item.IconFileName = data.file.name;

        }

    });
```

the method does execute as expected.  However, updating the value of self.item.IconFileName when the above method executes does not update in the ui.  Below is my html.

```
<input id="IconFile" class="form-control control-label col-md-2" type="text" ng-bind="cc.item.IconFileName">
```

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: can you share code where you are triggering `fileSelected` event ? and what is `self` variable in this code ? and why inside event you are updating `self.item.IconFileName`  and in template you are binding `cc.item.IconFileName` ?

Comment: if I bind value="{{cc.item.IconFileName}}" it works.

Comment: are `cc` and `self` same object ?

Comment: @jad-panda - yes, controller as syntax.  I needed to call $scope.apply for the model values to be updated and shown in the ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to call $scope.apply

```
$scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, data) {

          $scope.$apply(function() {
            switch (data.model) {
            case "PromotionalLargeImageFile":
                self.item.PromtionalLargeImageFile = data.file;
                self.item.PromtionalLargeImageFileName = data.file.name;
                break;
            case "PromotionalThumbnailImageFile":
                self.item.PromotionalThumbnailImageFile = data.file;
                self.item.PromotionalThumbnailImageFileName = data.file.name;
                break;
            default:
                self.item.MiniMiniIconFile = data.file;
                self.item.MiniMiniIconFileName = data.file.name;
            }

        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$timeout` instead of `$scope.$apply`, if possible. `$scope.$apply` can raise *`$digest already in progress`* error. for more information you can see this answer [Angular $scope.$apply vs $timeout as a safe $apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23073968/1309864)

```
$scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, data) {
       $timeout(function() {
            switch (data.model) {
               case "PromotionalLargeImageFile":
                  self.item.PromtionalLargeImageFile = data.file;
                  self.item.PromtionalLargeImageFileName = data.file.name;
                  break;
              case "PromotionalThumbnailImageFile":
                  self.item.PromotionalThumbnailImageFile = data.file;
                  self.item.PromotionalThumbnailImageFileName = data.file.name;
                  break;
              default:
                  self.item.MiniMiniIconFile = data.file;
                  self.item.MiniMiniIconFileName = data.file.name;
            }
      });
});
```