# Socket.IO message doesn't update Angular variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I have a socket.io client-server setup with AngularJS running on the client.

```
// Server.js
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    //console.log(msg);
    console.log(msg);
    io.emit('message', msg);
 });
});
```

As observed, it essentially emits a `message` events with the data stored in the variable `msg`.

And then I have the following client code.

```
var container = angular.module("AdminApp", []);

container.controller("StatsController", function($scope) {

    var socket = io.connect();

    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        $scope.frontEnd = msg;
    });
});
```

I now am facing a weird problem. When I write the following code snippet to print `frontEnd`, it doesn't show up. But the `console.log(msg);` works and it shows me the data emitted from the variable `msg`.

```
<body ng-app="AdminApp">

    <div ng-controller="StatsController">
        <p>{{frontEnd}}</p> //Doesn't show anything
    </div>

</body>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to wrap the change of the model (changing properties on the `$scope`), with `$scope.$apply(function() {})` in order to to update the view.

```
var container = angular.module("AdminApp", []);

    container.controller("StatsController", function($scope) {

        var socket = io.connect();

        socket.on('message', function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            $scope.$apply(function() { $scope.frontEnd = msg; });
        });
    });
```

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

From the official [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because `socket.on('message', function (msg) {..` is out of angular knowledge. its something happening outside the angular.

Then if you o something outside of the angular then you have to tell the angular to update since there are something to update

use `$scope.$apply()` after the `$scope.frontEnd = msg;`

Or **more preferably** wrap it in the `$timeout` as,

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.frontEnd = msg;
});
```

here is a good [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070822/angular-scope-apply-vs-timeout-as-a-safe-apply) why `$timeout` is more preferable.