# Socket.io run function on update

Tags: angularjs, sockets, socket.io

How do I run a function when socket.io updates a variable. It seems that $watch does not work or purhaps I am doing something wrong.

```
$http.get('/api/availabilitys/' + myId).then(response => {
  $scope.availability = response.data;
  socket.syncUpdates('availability', $scope.availability);
});


$scope.$watch('availability', function() {
  console.log('test'); //This is not printing on update
  angular.forEach(self.location, function (loc){
    loc.availability = $scope.availability.filter(function (a){
      return a.loc === loc._id;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: in your `$http.get` after updating the values, try doing `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: Does not help. The test prints the first time around. It does not print on update.

Answer (score 0):

The functions have to be in the same controller / scope because of **encapsulation**. The $scope of angular does not know if socket.io updates a variable, use a `socket.on()` listener to trigger the angular $watch

**Try the code in this thread [Socket.IO message doesn't update Angular variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976934/socket-io-message-doesnt-update-angular-variable)**

Instead of $watch in angular you can use socket.on() of socket.io

```
 var container = angular.module("AdminApp", []);

 container.controller("StatsController", function($scope) {

var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    $scope.$apply(function() { $scope.frontEnd = msg; });
});
});
```

See (the posts at the end of) this thread 
[How do I use $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs)

Comment: I know how to use $watch. My question is why is my socket update not triggering the $watch.

Comment: The $watch should work. What does not seem to work is the socket update. The socket update is outside of the 'scope' of angular see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976934/socket-io-message-doesnt-update-angular-variable

Comment: My socket update is working as the $scope.availability variable is updating in the UI so angular is aware of it.

Comment: Is the variable 'avasilibility' defined inside the scope that the $watch listens to ? this is the key point...

Comment: Yes it is setup in the same scope.

Comment: try the socket.on() listener above. Maybe there has first to be executed a listener that triggers the $watch / $digest at all. See the last post of this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs