# Trigger the digest cycle in callback events

Tags: angularjs, callback, handsontable, angularjs-digest

I want to create a corresponding textarea along with a handstontable, such that modifying the table has impact to the text, and vice-versa. Here is a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/quresud/1/edit?html,console,output).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
    <script src="https://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/dist/ngHandsontable.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <hot-table settings="settings" on-after-create-row="onAfterCreateRow" datarows="dataJson"></hot-table>
        <br><br>
        <textarea cols=40 rows=20 ng-model="dataString"></textarea>
    </div>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngHandsontable']);
    app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$filter', 'hotRegisterer', function ($scope, $filter, hotRegisterer) {
        $scope.dataJson = [[5, 6], [7, 8]];

        $scope.onAfterCreateRow = function (index, amount) {
            $scope.$digest();
        };

        $scope.$watch('dataJson', function (dataJson_new) {
            $scope.dataString = $filter('json')(dataJson_new);
        }, true);

        $scope.$watch('dataString', function (dataString_new) {
            try {
                $scope.dataJson = JSON.parse(dataString_new);
            } catch (e) {
            }
        }, true);

        $scope.settings = {
            contextMenu: true,
            contextMenuCopyPaste: {
                swfPath: 'zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.swf'
            }
        };
    }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, one thing I realise is that, adding/deleting rows/columns will NOT fire the watcher of `dataJSON` (whereas modifying a cell value will do). So I have to use `$scope.$digest()` in the callbacks such as `onAfterCreateRow` to reflect the change of adding rows. But it raises `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'forceFullRender' of null`:

[image: screen shot 2017-02-01 at 17 07 55]

Having `$scope.$digest()` in other callbacks (i.e., `onAfterCreateCol`, `onAfterRemoveRow` and `onAfterRemoveCol`) will raise the same error. I think it is a serious problem, if we cannot well trigger the digest cycle in these callback events. Does anyone know how to solve this or have any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$timeout` was a workaround in some older versions of angular currently, you can use `$applyAsync` that was created to replace the $timeout as workaround and work for the cases where you would get an error `$digest already in progress`

Comment: indeed, `$scope.$applyAsync()` works. And `$scope.$evalAsync()` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to fix this problem is to use `$timeout` service which implements so called . See here updated [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/sucicepexa/edit?html,console,output). Also, to see explanation of how `$timeout` works read the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070822/angular-scope-apply-vs-timeout-as-a-safe-apply). Hope this will help.